# How to Fetch Photos uploaded by Users at a listed Business- Google + local

Tags: google-plus, google-places-api, google-places

HI am trying to get the photos uploaded by users at a local business 
( business listed in  Google +).

For ex

From the below URL which is pointing to REX theater in Bangalore, I want to fetch the photos uploaded by the users.

https://plus.google.com/111678408090599994953/photos

I have tried using google places api and Place details api but none of them seem to be giving any photo related info.

Would be great if i can get the photo's at a place uploaded by Google Users.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** The Places API now supports the return of one place photo if available for a [Place Search request](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) and up to ten place photos for a [Place Details request](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details).

If a photos array is returned with your request, you can pass the `photo_reference` from a contained photo object to a [Place Photo request](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos) with the `maxheight` and/or `maxwidth`, `sensor` and `key` parameters:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRvAAAAwMpdHeWlXl-lH0vp7lez4znKPIWSWvgvZFISdKx45AwJVP1Qp37YOrH7sqHMJ8C-vBDC546decipPHchJhHZL94RcTUfPa1jWzo-rSHaTlbNtjh-N68RkcToUCuY9v2HNpo5mziqkir37WU8FJEqVBIQ4k938TI3e7bf8xq-uwDZcxoUbO_ZJzPxremiQurAYzCTwRhE_V0&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

Please see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the Info i have subscribed to the future changes of the Feature request.